# When will SQLite through SQLITE_IOERR_SHMMAP error? SQLite C library

Tags: sqlite, memory, load

I am getting error **SQLITE_IOERR_SHMMAP** continiously in my application. This error comes when there is a high load on the machine(caused by my application). On low/normal loads I don't see this error. Once the load increase this errors comes every time, within 10mins.

Getting this for prepare and step operations.

[SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#ioerr_shmmap) describes this as:

> The SQLITE_IOERR_SHMMAP error code is an extended error code for SQLITE_IOERR indicating an I/O error within the xShmMap method on the sqlite3_io_methods object while trying to map a shared memory segment into the process address space.

Honestly, I am not skilled to understand this explaination. Reaching out the help.

**SQLite lbrary version**: 3.2
**Machine**: RHEL 8/7
**load average**: "649.16, 817.75, 726.10" (can go more)
**CPUs**: 24 (i3en.6xlarge AWS machine)

I looked for solutions online. People facing this issue is mostly due to [WAL mode on network file system](https://groups.google.com/g/orthanc-users/c/vDBeDSGwJ-g).
In my case things work okay on normal loads.